# Browser closes right after starting Selenium test with Python, giving a BROWSER_SWITCHER_SERVICE.CC(238) error

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote a simple Python script using Selenium that should visit "http://sistemas.macae.rj.gov.br/transparencia/index.asp?acao=3&item=10", fill in the fields and click on "Gerar" button. But when I run it, I get this error message:

> DevTools listening on
>   ws://127.0.0.1:49978/devtools/browser/4a5508bd-995e-4f96-930e-438a09865a69
>   [15056:4140:0418/161952.737:ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238)]
>   XXX Init()

My config:
- Python 3.7.6
- Selenium 3.141.0
- Windows 10
- Chrome Browser version 81.0.4044.113 (I'm already using **driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install()** to use the correct chromedriver)

Any thoughts on why do I get this error and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

[Print of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q4z6.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem with Chrome Browser version 81.0.4044.122. Deleting the "old" ChromeDriver file and downloading 81.0.4044.69 solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's right

But work in this code. I  think it problem in x-path. if you go with id it will work

```
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass

username = 'xxxxxxx'
password1 = 'xxxxxxx'
# capecha = getpass("Capecha")

driver = webdriver.Chrome("c:\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://xxxxxxxx.aspx")

username_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("txtusr")
username_textbox.send_keys(username)
password = driver.find_element_by_id("txtpwd")
password.send_keys(password1)
login_button = driver.find_element_by_id("btnSubmit")
login_button.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

This error comes up when there is version mismatch between the browser and driver. You should try updating your Chrome browser and first try installing the latest driver for Chrome.

If that works with driver, then you can try using `webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install()`